# High queued waiting for a read lock in secondary mongodb

Tags: mongodb, performance, database-performance

I am having high number of locks on a specific node of my replicaset. The connections between them are distributed on all nodes.
The configuration are the same in OS Version / Hardware / Mongo version

The opsmanager show the message in the graph is: The number of operations queued waiting for a read lock

[Queues Graphic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KoBO6.jpg)

Comment: Hence, your question is?

Comment: Hi, my question is how reduce this high ratio of locks.